# C# Mongodb Add Field

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert, updates, mongodb-.net-driver

I am getting stucked finding solution to my problem. I google it but seems no results. I wanted to add an existing collection as a field to another collection. I have two collection named `products` and `product_update`. Both collection have both `ean` field. And so, I wanted to add a `product_update` collection as a field to `products` by which they have both same `ean`. Here is my code:

```
var collection1 = Database.GetCollection<Entity>("products");
var collection2 = Database.GetCollection<Update>("product_update");
var productupdate = collection2.FindAll();
foreach (var a in productupdate)
{
    try
    {
        var b = collection1.FindOne(Query.EQ("product.ean",a.ean));

        BsonDocument product_update = new BsonDocument{
            {"ean",a.ean},
            {"categody",a.category},
            {"list_price_excl_tax",a.list_price_excl_tax},
            {"list_price_incl_tax",a.list_price_incl_tax},
            {"cost_price",a.cost_price},
            {"stock",a.stock},
            {"weight",a.weight},
            {"currency",a.currency},
            {"price_type",a.price_type}
        };
        //then I wanted to insert this product_update to variable b/query
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `insert this product_update to variable b/query`. Could you clarify?  Are you just wanting to attach the `BsonDocument` to `collection1`?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean.

Comment: Not the answer but if you used the strongly-typed `UpdateBuilder` and `QueryBuilder` this would be much easier to maintain.

Comment: You might want to update the terminology in your question: you cannot store a `collection` in a field; you can have a field containing an array of nested documents.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to your entity to hold the updates:

```
 public List<Update> Updates {get; set;}
```

Then use the MongoDB operator `$push` to add your update to this field.  See the [documentation on $push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) for more information.

NOTE that if you do this AND you also store the update in the update collection you are storing copies of your data and cannot simply modify the update once it has been added.  You may want to instead either join the two collections manually at query time (i.e. fetch the Entity and then fetch all the Updates for it) OR you might want to simply eliminate the Update collection entirely and store them only inside Entities.

Based on what you've shown so far it looks like eliminating the collection for Updates and simply nesting them as complex objects inside the Entity is the right way to go since an Update cannot stand-alone.

BUT if you expect a very large number of updates you cannot do that since you'll exceed the maximum document size so you'd be back to storing them separately.